# Implementing a software gimbal

Tags: spatial, noise-reduction

I have a game controller (e.g. Wii) which gives me in software its position and orientation.

The given spatial data has a lot of noise, both because of the hardware, and because the user is a human, and human hands aren't stable.

I want to implement something similar to a gimbal, to stabilize the input and remove noise.
Ideally, if the hand is held in place, the spatial data should stay the same, even if in reality the hand moves a little bit.
And when the hand is moving, the data should be stable and smooth, and not all jiggly and noisy.

I tried simple things like a moving average, but it's really not as effective as an actual gimbal.

Searching for anything related to "gimbal" either results in game rotation math (gimbal lock), or electronics projects that use a physical gimbal.

Are there any resources related to stabilizing spatial data?

Comment: are you sure that a gimbal is something that stabilises input signals? AFAIK a gimbal just provides a single and stable point-of-reference for the rotations. You are most probably after noise-reduction algorithms/techniques, moving-average being one of them and the Kalman filter being another technique worth trying out.